# Why doesn't QString treat special characters correctly, when no QCoreApplication has been instantiated?

Tags: qt, special-characters

I started writing a very basic text manipulation application in Qt, without a GUI. 
My text contained special characters, but somehow I was not able to print those special characters, no matter what I did. 
I then noticed, that after adding a `QCoreApplication` instance (which I had previously removed, because I thought I wouldn't need it), everything worked just as it should.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString s(QString::fromUtf8("aä\xc3\xa4")); // aää

    qDebug() << s;
    qDebug() << s.toAscii();
    qDebug() << s.toLatin1();
    qDebug() << s.toUtf8();
    qDebug() << s.toLocal8Bit();
    qDebug("%s", qPrintable(s));

    qDebug("%i", s.length());
    qDebug("%i", strlen(qPrintable(s)));

    return 0;
}
```

Output with `QCoreApplication` (everything works as it should):

```
"aää" 
"aää" 
"aää" 
"aÃ¤Ã¤" 
"aÃ¤Ã¤" 
aää
3
5
```

Output after commenting out the line, where `QCoreApplication` is defined (special characters are not shown anymore):

```
"a" 
"a" 
"a" 
"a" 
"a" 
a
3
1
```

Note, that already after calling `qPrintabable(s)`, the special characters are already removed. 
I tested this to be sure, that `QDebug` is not the problem.

I also checked if the file is really encoded in UTF-8.

Why doesn't QString treat special characters correctly, when no `QCoreApplication` has been instantiated?

Comment: Yery interesting question... I guess that the reason might be within `QTextCodec` or `QTextStream`, but I might be wrong. `QDebug` uses a `QTextStream`, but as you have noticed, the `qPrintable` (which is only a shorthand for `.toLocal8Bit().constData()`) already magically removes your non-ascii characters, or inserts a `'\0'`, since this is the only explanation why `strlen` should return 1.

Comment: Inserting `'\0'` is not the case, as I have tested other strings as `"aäa"`, where other letters follow after a special character. They are not removed. In other words, if `s` is `"aäa"`, the output when not using `QCoreApplication` is `"aa"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going through Qt's source code, I stumbled across this code called when `QCoreApplication` is constructed:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_UNIX
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");                // use correct char set mapping
    qt_locale_initialized = true;
#endif
```

In other words, on "Unix" systems, the `QCoreApplication` constructor is making a call to `setlocale` (found in `locale.h`), which is used to set the program's current locale.  This ultimately affects the output from `qDebug`, which relies on `QTextStream`, which ultimately uses what it believes is the system-defined locale to create its output.

When I tested your code on a Linux system, I encountered the same result that you did.  On a Windows system, commenting-out the `QCoreApplication` construction had no impact on the results.  I also noticed that printing out the original string through `printf` gave the correct result regardless of whether `QCoreApplication` was constructed.

Comment: so is this a bug, or does Qt specify that one has to initialize a `Q(Core)Application` before using other Qt components or classes?

Comment: @Misch Qt specifies the conditions under which one must initialize a Q(Core)Application.  Refer to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html.  This particular behavior is documented under the "Locale Settings" section.